# nginx redirect to https:// redirect loop

Tags: loops, redirect, nginx, https

i am using nginx php-fpm, i want to redirect my site abcde.com to always use https and www

i add the following rule on my nginx.conf to redirect http and non www to https + www,

```
return 301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;
```

the config in above is working well, and then i will redirect visitor https://abcde.com to https://www.abcde.com and then i added the same rule on snginx.conf (config for ssl) but my browser show looping redirect/the page isn't redirected properly by chrome and firefox

if i remove the rule on snginx.conf the site work well, i have tried the following rule but still error redirect loop:

```
return 301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;
return 301 $scheme://www.$server_name$request_uri;
return 301 $scheme://www.abcde.pw$request_uri;
return 301 https://www.abcde.pw$request_uri;
return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
```

this is my snginx.conf

```
server {
    listen      xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443 ssl spdy;
    server_name abcde.com www.abcde.com;

    root        /home/admin/web/abcde.com/public_html;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/abcde.com.log combined;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/abcde.com.bytes bytes;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/domains/abcde.com.error.log error;

    ssl         on;
    ssl_certificate      /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.abcde.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.abcde.com.key;
    ssl_dhparam /home/admin/conf/web/dhparam.pem;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
```